# Android Service And Lenovo

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to make App that will communicate with Bluetooth device. i have a service which set connection, get data from Bluetooth & collect it to int array, and sent users settings to device. Then when App ask for new Data service return array.When user change some data in App it sent it to Service and service sent it back to bluetooth*. I have tested this app on Sony Z, HTC, Samsung Tab2 - it works fine... But on ZTE, and Lenovo i have problems! The main problem that this devices have slow speed on reading socket.getInputStream(); too slow... i have a great delay... with data reading. And the App Crashes.

Why it so?

- I think, i ll try to make to Threads in Service for get and sent data... but on devices Sony HTC Samsung.. it works fine! By the way Samsung have only 500 mb RAM (damaged) ZTE Blade and Lenovo Tablet must be more faster!

Comment: So, my English is rather bad. But i'll try to explain this problem.

Comment: There some difference in priority of processes in OS on China Device and another systems. China device give more resources % for an Activity that uses words with in this moment. But background process have no enough processor time to parse incoming Stream of Data. When i decrease speed it's start to work amazing!

Comment: My next step is to send more different values, and maybe speed (of DataStream) will be not enough for real time data. I have no idea how to make China Devices spend more CPU time on background service... iF anyone can helps? Thanks!